# Bootstrap columns not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, frontend

I am trying to have 12 columns, which would take up 1 column each on a large screen, and 4 columns each on a small screen. But when I try to minimize it, nothing happens, they just get pushed one underneath another. I wanted to have 3 columns in one row on small screens, but that doesn't happen and I am wondering what I am doing wrong here. Can you please help me out without adding negative reputation to the post?
Thank you!

Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-warning">Warning</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-info">Info</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-danger">Cancel</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-success">Yes</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-warning">Warning</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-info">Info</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-danger">Cancel</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-success">Yes</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-warning">Warning</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-info">Info</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-danger">Cancel</div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-success">Yes</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `col-xs` is **not available** in bootstrap 4.

For "xs" you have to use "col" only. Like: `col-4`;

To learn more take a look at bootstraps [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/).

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is no "col-xs-" in bootstrap 4. so use "col-" for small screen

```
.col-sm for larger mobile phones (devices with resolutions ≥ 576px);
.col-md for tablets (≥768px);
.col-lg for laptops (≥992px);
.col-xl for desktops (≥1200px)
```

Comment: yes exactly, but this was my way of finding that out:)